# laravel route with machine ip address instade localhost

Tags: laravel

I am trying to access my larvel 5.7 app with my machine ip like 
http://xx.xx.xx.81/testLog/public/auth here whene I submit to any controller  i get 404 error. Although i can access my app perfectly with localhost like http://localhost/testLog/public/auth. Please help me to fix it.
I have done this before on laravel 5.1 by placing index.php and .htaccess file at root folder of project. But the same thing is not working in 5.7.
I have done virtual hosting on my local aapche machine. there i can access it properly the url looks like xx.xx.xx.81/auth.

Comment: you need to define port like xx.xx.xx.81:8000

Comment: if you are using apache you should enable rewrite module by writing this in to the console.   `sudo a2enmod rewrite`

Comment: why not try with this command:" php artisan serve --host=MACHINE_IP --port=8080 "

Comment: I  have freshly created another laravel 5.7 project with composer and it is working with both localhost and ip .So I believe  some how I had corrupted the previous project.Thanks every body